# How to read a query from a text file, modify it, and call it

Tags: prolog, weka, swi-prolog, arff

I have a [Weka arff file](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html), where the attributes are Prolog queries.

I want to read the query from the file, modify it, and then run the query.

The weka arff file begins like:

```
@relation propositionalization
@attribute 'link(_, A, _), link(A, _, _)' {'+'}
@attribute 'reaction(A, 0), link(A, B, _), link(B, C, _), reaction(C, 1), link(B, D, activation), reaction(D, 0), reaction(B, 0), link(A, E, _), link(E, F, follows), reaction(F, 1)' {'+','-'}
@attribute 'reaction(A, 0), link(A, B, _), link(B, C, _), reaction(C, 1), reaction(B, 1), link(A, D, _), link(D, E, follows), reaction(E, 0)' {'+','-'}
```

etc

I have a dcg made up of:

```
list([]) -->[].
list([L|Ls]) --> [L],list(Ls).
get_feature(Feature) --> "@attribute '",list(Feature), "'",list(_).
```

I read the file with:

```
read_my_file(File,Lines):-
open(File,read,Stream,[]),
    read_lines(Lines,Stream),!.

read_lines([H|T],Stream):-
  read_line_to_codes(Stream,H), H\=end_of_file, read_lines(T,Stream).

read_lines([],Stream):-close(Stream).
```

And use the following to call phrase/2 to extract the feature as a code list.

```
lineCodes_feature(Line,Feature):-
 phrase(get_feature(Feature),Line),!.
```

I then call:

```
read_my_file('my_file.arff',Lines), 
member(Line,Lines), 
lineCodes_feature(Line,Feature), 
atom_codes(Atom,Feature).
```

And back track to see each feature as an atom.

I am stuck at the next step of modifying and running this as a query.
I want to change the reaction/2 terms to reaction/3 where the additional argument will be the same for each term.

So for example the atomic term

```
'reaction(A, 0), link(A, B, _), link(B, C, _), reaction(C, 1), reaction(B, 1), link(A, D, _), link(D, E, follows), reaction(E, 0)'
```

Would I imagine become a list :

```
[reaction(newarg,A, 0), link(A, B, _), link(B, C, _), reaction(newarg,C, 1), reaction(newarg,B, 1), link(A, D, _), link(D, E, follows), reaction(newarg,E, 0)]
```

Which would allow me to somehow use call/1 to query the internal database?

Any help or comments on my approach appreciated.

Comment: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

I think its here, I am only interested in the beginning of the file, where attributes are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use [read_term_from_codes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=codesio:read_term_from_codes/3), then call the outcome term.

```
...
read_term_from_codes(Feature, Callable, []),
transform(Callable, Transformed),
Transformed,
...
```

An example, using [library(dcg/basics)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/dcg/basics.pl) and [phrase_from_file](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=phrase_from_file/2)/2 to ease parsing

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

sw :- phrase_from_file(arff_file, '/home/carlo/test/x.weka').

arff_file --> [] ; arff_line, arff_file.

arff_line -->
    "@relation propositionalization", eol.
arff_line -->
    "@attribute '", string(Codes), "'",
    {read_term_from_codes(Codes, Prolog, []),
     transform_conjunction(Prolog,Transf),
     format('~w ->~n ~w~n', [Prolog, Transf])},
    string(_), eol.
arff_line -->
    eol.

eol --> "\n".

transform_conjunction((A,B),(C,D)) :- transform_term(A,C), !, transform_conjunction(B,D).
transform_conjunction(A,C) :- transform_term(A,C).

transform_term(reaction(B,C), reaction(newArg,B,C)).
transform_term(T, T).
```

Comment: `phrase_from_file/2` --> +1!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have not had a chance to look at it yet, just so you know.